# Major problem in quality of video in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In application i use the surface view camera to capture the video ,but the quality of video output very poor compared to actual camera output , i use basic android 2.1 version , i don`t know where i made the mistake, please any one help me put to capture the video with better quality.

i Don`t know where i made the mistake, i set the following properties for camera

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the code to record high quality video in android 2.1 by setting videEncodingBitRate , AudioEncodingBitRate, AudioSamplingRate ...etc. Using this method you can set the properties for video whatever you want to provide high quality video.

For setting high quality and low quality parameter refer this page,

http://www.andgps.com/20110410/camcorderprofile-predefined-camcorder-profile-settings-for-camcorder-applications

The code i used with base version android 2.1 to produce high quality video is shown below,`recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        Method[] methods = recorder.getClass().getMethods();

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
    recorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);

    for (Method method: methods){
    try{
        if (method.getName().equals("setAudioChannels")){
                method.invoke(recorder, String.format("audio-param-number-of-channels=%d", 1));
        } 
        else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate")){
                method.invoke(recorder,12200);
            }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder, 3000000);
        }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder,8000);
        }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder,24);
        }
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

`